# Undo changes (commited and pushed)

Tags: git

I have two commit's which I have already commited and pushed.
I need to return the code to state 'two commits ago'.

I can use `git reset --hard <hash>` to do it locally, but I can not push this changes:

> hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind

How can I return the code to some previous commit in the central repository?

**Update:**

```
ms-app-actual/mobile-application » git reset --hard e50fa38c4865bd82fce7ddcf1e05d94012266364   ‹master›
HEAD is now at e50fa38 Move Attachment class to separate Project
  ms-app-actual/mobile-application » git push --force                                            ‹master›
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: You don't have permission
To ssh://git@aaa.bb.cc.dd:2222/ms-mobile-app/mobile-application.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@aaa.bb.cc.dd:2222/ms-mobile-app/mobile-application.git'
```

But I can pull:

```
ms-app-actual/mobile-application » git pull                                                    ‹master›
Updating e50fa38..cebcabf
Fast-forward
```

and make ordinary commits.

I am using Gitlab.

Comment: What about `git push --force`?

Comment: @raina77ow Since that's the right answer, why don't you post it as one?

Comment: It looks like forced pushes are disabled on your gitlab instance. Are you administering the instance?

Comment: Yes, I have admin rights

Comment: Even an owner cannot force push to the protected branches - and `master` is (as a 'default' branch) a protected one. You always can unprotect it, though, via Settings -> Protected branches menu.

Comment: Protected branches must be a GitLab specific feature as this is the first I've heard of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a `git reset --hard` and force pushing the changes will remove the commits.  However, you need to be careful doing this.  If anyone else has pulled your changes, it will cause problems with their history.  And it seems that Gitlab is preventing you from doing this anyway.

The best way would be to create a new commit that undoes the changes and push that.  This way anyone that pulls will not have any issues merging in the changes.  There are a couple of ways of doing this.

1) Create two revert commits and rebase them into one

```
git revert <sha of commit 1>
git revert <sha of commit 2>
git rebase -i <sha of commit is in good state>
//Squash the two revert commits into one
git push
```

2) Checkout all the changed files from the good commit and commit those changes

```
git diff --name-only HEAD..HEAD~3 | xargs git checkout HEAD~3 -- 
//This should result in all the files modified in the two commits being changed.
git commit -am "Reverting changes from commits"
git push
```

Both of these solutions, basically result in the same thing.  A new commit that is the inverse of the changes that you made in the two that you don't want.  This is the safest way to undo changes that were pushed to a remote repository.

As a rule of thumb: Once you push changes to a remote repository, you should consider them permanent.

Since you also tried to do `reset --hard`, in order to get the commits so that you can undo them.  All that you need to do is `git pull`.